# FCM Gradle Updation

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't update

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4
```

to

```
 com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3
```

11.0.4 is working fine. classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' is also added in my dependencies.

My Gradle code

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev181-1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: So what is the error ?

Comment: Error:The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.4,11.0.4]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: Share your `build.gradle` with question

Comment: use this command and share the result , it has some mixing versions in your dependencies. gradlew app:dependencies

Comment: hey you need to use same firebase library version for messaging, core and ads.

Comment: @HarinKaklotar Ads is now commented

Comment: I think `firebase-core` module use `play-services-basement` with version 16.0.1 and `com.google.android.gms` also uses this module with 11.0.4 version. And it causes to crash.

Answer (score 0):

The latest stable available version is `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2`. Android Studio should notify you about it, when you move your cursor on this line.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your build.gradle file :

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have a same version name with Firebase and Playservice library . So  Please **replace your libraries**.

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
```

**with this lines**

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

update the Google Play Services libraries:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
```

because the `11.0.4` versions will cause the conflict.